# How to use custom device tree source correctly in buildroot?

Tags: u-boot, buildroot

I made a copy of the dts from `<linux>/board/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx28-evk.dts` for using with my custom board. My custom device-tree is named `imx28-custom.dts` and is pointed in the *Out of tree custom DTS* menu entry (`BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_DTS_PATH`) in the Buildroot config.

However u-boot is configured to use the existing MX28 board config. After building a kernel I have `imx28-custom.dtb` and `zImage` in the `<buildroot>/output/images` folder.

When the system boots, u-boot tells that `imx28-evk.dtb` is not found. Why was `imx28-custom.dtb` built but is not found by u-boot? Why u-boot doesn't find its own device-tree (`imx28-evk.dtb`) for itself and my custom device-tree for the kernel? I assumed that `BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_DTS_PATH` relates only to the kernel. How can my custom device-tree be passed to the kernel if u-boot tries to use its own `imx28-evk.dtb` for this?

Answer (score 4):

U-Boot complaining about not finding the device-tree is related to the Linux kernel: when booting, U-Boot loads the device-tree and kernel image from the storage to specified addresses in the memory, and then passes control to the kernel. The default configuration for the i.MX28-EVK board is to pass the `imx28-evk.dtb` file.

The `BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_DTS_PATH` only serves to include the custom device-tree in the files to build and install but **does not** configure U-Boot to use it.

Which device-tree U-Boot passes to the kernel is defined by U-Boot's `CONFIG_DEFAULT_FDT_FILE` option (you can edit this by typing `make uboot-menuconfig` (see my note at the end) then going under *Boot* to set the *Default fdt file*). This option should be set to something like `imx28-custom.dtb`.

How to configure U-Boot from Buildroot is described [here](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#_configuration_of_other_components) and [here to make them permanent](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#customize-store-package-config).

---

In the case of the i.MX28-EVK, Buildroot uses the *Legacy* build system (which is to be used up to u-boot 2015.04, but the config uses 2020.04) which does not allow the use of the `make uboot-menuconfig` command. You should safely be able to change that. You need to set the *Build system* to `Kconfig` and set the *Board defconfig* to `mx28evk`.

Comment: "*Which device-tree u-boot passes to the kernel is defined by u-boot's `CONFIG_DEFAULT_FDT_FILE` option*" - Not 100% accurate for all arches/boards. Instead some boards only use `CONFIG_DEFAULT_DEVICE_TREE` because they might use the same **dtb** file for both U-Boot and the kernel, or there's confusion between which config option to use.